# How to send a variable through email

Tags: python

I am trying to send a 2 step verification code for an assignment and everything works but when i recieve the email there is no number. For Loop creates random 6 digit code. It says: Please confirm your login by entering this 2-step verification code. None'

I have looked on stack over flow for solutions and google etc

```
def TwoStep():

    for x in range(1):

            RandomNumber = print(random.randint(100000,1000000))


    time.sleep(5)

    email_send = 'recieving email'
    email_user = 'myemail'
    email_password = 'password'

    subject = '2-Step Verification'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject


    body = ('Please confirm your login by entering this 2-step verification code. ' + str(RandomNumber))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))


    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,email_password)

    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
    server.quit()

TwoStep()
```

Be able to send the 6 digit code through email.

Comment: The loop *prints* numbers, and the return value of `print` is `None`- so that's what your `RandomNumber` contains. Just remove the `print` function call: `RandomNumber = random.randint(100000,1000000)`

Answer (score 2):

A few things to comment:

1) `print(random.randint(100000,1000000))` prints the number in the console but doesn't returns anything, that's why you are getting a `None` value.

2) **DON'T** use capital case variables, by convention these names are reserved for naming Classes and it's confusing to see this names as a variable. Note that even the SO highlighting marks it in another color. Use some camel-case or snake-case naming such as `randomNumber` or `random_number` (these one more common in Python).

3) Is the for loop even necessary? I think you only need to generate a random number, so you can remove the loop around it, and just assign it once.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not returning a random number instead printing it and why is loop added ?

```
for x in range(1):
    RandomNumber = print(random.randint(100000,1000000))
```